# Cannot get model's data

Tags: sapui5

I define json model in `onInit()` function of the controller:

```js
var oSelectedFields = {};
oSelectedFields.counter = 0;
var oSelectedFieldsModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
oSelectedFieldsModel.setData(oSelectedFields);
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oSelectedFieldsModel, "selectedFieldsCounter");
console.log("oninit(). ",oSelectedFields); //(1)
```

Then, in one of the functions I want to get this model's data, use it and update it (the function is called on `press` event):

```js
function(oEvent){
    var oSelectedFields = sap.ui.getCore().getModel("selectedFieldsCounter").getData();
    console.log(oSelectedFields);//(2)
    oSelectedFields.counter++;
    //rest of the function's code here
}
```

Line (1) displays `oninit().  Object {counter: 0}` and line (2) displays `Object {}`.

If I call the function for the second time, line (2) displays `Object {counter: NaN}`

The question is why I cannot get the data of the model?

Comment: The above code works for me. Would require information about the folder structure of your application to check why the issue occurs.

Comment: @Veeraraghavan everything is in the same controller (in my app I have 1 view and 1 controller files).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a variable interference error in the model declaration.

After the model declaration I declared another model with empty object.

By error, I assigned that empty object to the first model.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working. Check if this link is of use [Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/XRfRYAkzteX9U5zVvKpc?p=preview)

```
 var oSelectedFields = sap.ui.getCore().getModel("selectedFieldsCounter").getData();
            console.log(oSelectedFields);//(2)
            oSelectedFields.counter++;
```

I have done with a simple button where i retrieve the model data and print it in console.
 You could use this code and make it work for you. Else you can add your failing code that needs to be checked further.
I think you would be using the 2-way binding and hence the model is being changed by some action.

Comment: Looks like in "clean" environment the code works fine. The question is what could affect the model and how do I fix it. In the question I have shown all the places in the app that use that model and all the operations on that model.

Comment: Generally setting the model on sap.ui.getCore() is not advisable especially if you are running on the Launchpad because multiple applications are running in the mode. Could you tell me where are you running the app. Is it a standalone scenario or within some other environment

Comment: I got this issue when I was testing the app from the WEB IDE (using the "RUN" button or Alt+F5). This was the only app I was running. I tried to set the model to the view, not globally (to the core). but it didn't help.

Comment: I got this working on WebIde as well.Looks like the model data is being interfered with in some form.in your example